# Flutter Navigating and Keeping BottomNavBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I want to have a navigation like instagram. I will have a bottom navigation bar and each of its items I want to navigate other pages as an example in categories I want to navigate categories detail page and still keep the bottom nav bar.

I tried routers but I am no expert so I failed and there is little information about that.
I tried *IndexedStack* didn't work.
I tried wrapping my apps body with Navigator. It worked a little but not the way I wanted to.
In this last method I lost my bottom nav bar after clicking categoriesdetails
[I want to click those to navigate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZi36.png)
In each of those buttons I will navigate to their own detail page but when I click them I lose my bottom navigation bar.
I tried other methods and one time I kept the bottom nav bar but when I clicked its items did not change my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you happened to check out [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). It has a nifty solution for this using the [ShellRoute](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html) which states :

> A route that displays a UI shell around the matching child route.

You can then go on and define a particular widget as the "shell" widget for all routes under it. Meaning it will be available for all routes under it.

You can check the [example linked](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html). If the example in the documentation is a bit hard to grasp, I went on to create an example for you to play with.

The live example is available on Zapp [here](https://zvfg06sxvfh0.zapp.page/#/) and the code itself can be viewed [here](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zvfg06sxvfh0?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart).

Please note I added only one sub-route for each main route. You can, however, add as many sub-routes as you want.

Comment: Actually I did but like you said it was very hard . But I guess nothing else can be done I need to learn go router . Thanks for your code it helps a lot !